# cannot access raspberry pi with a public ip address

Tags: raspberry-pi, portforwarding

I'm trying to run my own instance of a bitwarden vault on my raspberry pi.
Everything works well. I can access it from my local network. Yet I can't access it outside of it with my public ip even though I forwarded my port and I check they were open with nmap.

So I have a forwarded port, a server running that runs perfectly on my local network. But still can't acess it from any network.

Does anyone have a clue on why that doesn't work ?

Thanks !

Comment: This question seems to be about system and network administration, not programming.  Try one of the other Stack Exchange sites, e.g. http://superuser.com.

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it.